# Tablesorter does not sorting on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have implemented client side sorting for the gridview using Jquery TableSorter. But when my page the page loads for the first time, it is not displaying in the sorted order. I have to click on the header to display in the ascending order.  I’m allowing sortable option on only 2nd column. Implemented with SortList

```
$("#<%=gvDetails.ClientID%>").tablesorter({
                sortList: [2, 0],
                headers: {        
                    0: { sorter: false },
                    1: { sorter: false },
                    3: { sorter: false },
                    4: { sorter: false }
                }
            });
```

I'm getting this error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'count' of undefined
>   or null reference

Can someone please suggest mw how to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell which version of tablesorter you are using, but the [`sortList` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist)* needs to be set with an array of arrays ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1330/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    sortList: [ [0,0], [1,1] ]
});
```

* The `sortList` link is to my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), but the option setting is the same for both the original and the fork.